# Java: Eight Queens algorithm error

Tags: java, computer-science, backtracking

I saw a post here similar to this, but mine is slightly different.

I wrote the displayBoard method, but the last column doesn't return a Queen.

Is it because the queen has a value of 1 and is throwing off the numbers?

It keeps telling me I have an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException: -1`

I know that arrays count by 0 yet I still couldn't get this to work

---

```
public class Queens 
{
    public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

    public static final int EMPTY = 0;

    public static final int QUEEN = 1;

    private int board[][];

public Queens()
{
  board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
}

public void clearBoard()
{
    board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
}

public void displayBoard () {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) 
        {
            if (board[i][j] == QUEEN ) 
            {
                System.out.print("| X |");
                counter++;
            }
            else 
            {              
                System.out.print("| 0 |");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public boolean placeQueens(int column) {

if (column >= BOARD_SIZE) {
    return true;  // base case
}
else {
  boolean queenPlaced = false;
  int row = 1;  // number of square in column

  while ( !queenPlaced && (row <= BOARD_SIZE)  )  {
    // if square can be attacked
      if (isUnderAttack(row, column)) {
      ++row;  // consider next square in column
      } // end if
      else {  // place queen and consider next column
      setQueen(row, column);
      queenPlaced = placeQueens(column+1);
      // if no queen is possible in the next column,
      if (!queenPlaced) {
          // backtrack:  remove queen placed earliers
          // and try next square in column
          removeQueen(row, column);
          ++row;
      } // end if
      } // end if
  } // end while
  return queenPlaced;
} // end if
} // end placeQueens

private void setQueen(int row, int column) {
board[row-1][column-1] = QUEEN;
} // end setQueen

private void removeQueen(int row, int column) {
   board[row-1][column-1] = EMPTY;
} // end setQueen

private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column) {
// check column
for (int i=0; i<row-1; i++){
    if (board[i][column-1]==1){
        return true;
    }
}
// check row
for (int i=0; i<column-1; i++) {
    if (board[row-1][i] == 1){
        return true;
    }
}

// check lower diagnal
int lower_dir_row = row-2;
int lower_dir_column = column-2;
while (lower_dir_row>=0 && lower_dir_column>=0){
        if (board[lower_dir_row][lower_dir_column]==1){
            return true;
        } else {
            lower_dir_row = lower_dir_row -1;
            lower_dir_column = lower_dir_column -1;
        }
    }


 // check upper diagnal
int upper_dir_row = row;
int upper_dir_column = column-2;
while (upper_dir_row<BOARD_SIZE && upper_dir_column>=0){
    if(board[upper_dir_row][upper_dir_column] ==1){
        return true;
    }else{
        upper_dir_row = upper_dir_row +1;
        upper_dir_column = upper_dir_column -1;
    }
}
return false;

} // end isUnderAttack

public static void main(String[] s) 
{
    Queens q = new Queens();
    q.placeQueens(0);
    q.displayBoard();
}

} // end Queens
```

Comment: Where in the code does the error refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the while loop in your placeQueens() method

```
while ( !queenPlaced && (row <= BOARD_SIZE)  )  {...}
```

The while loop should be < to ensure that you never attempt to access your board at index BOARD_SIZE. Once the row == BOARD_SIZE you attempt to access the board which will throw the index out of bounds exception you are seeing. Change it to the following

```
while ( !queenPlaced && (row < BOARD_SIZE)  )  {...}
```

Furthermore, in your setQueen(...) and removeQueen(...) functions, you never do a bounds check and assume you can access the board with the passed in parameters. you need to ensure that both values are less than BOARD_SIZE before setting or removing the queen in your board array.

```
private void setQueen(int row, int column) {
    if(row - 1 < BOARD_SIZE && column - 1 < BOARD_SIZE)
        board[row-1][column-1] = QUEEN;
} // end setQueen

private void removeQueen(int row, int column) {
   if(row - 1 < BOARD_SIZE && column - 1 < BOARD_SIZE)
       board[row-1][column-1] = EMPTY;
} // end setQueen
```

Finally, since you are applying your own offest of 1 you should change the call in your main to (Credit @Ian Mc)

```
q.placeQueens(1);
```

However if you want to simplify your program you should not apply an offset as that will often introduce user bugs. **Here is what you should do to make your program work with no offset**

**(1)** Add checks inside your isUnderAttack method to ensure you are looking at valid rows and columns in your board before accessing them with a simple check that only checks 0 and greater values

```
private boolean isUnderAttack(int row, int column) {
// check column
for (int i=0; i<row-1; i++){
    /* add a check to ensure the column offset index is valid */
    if (column - 1 >= 0 && board[i][column-1]==1){
        return true;
    }
}
// check row
for (int i=0; i<column-1; i++) {
    /* add a check to ensure the row offset index is valid */
    if (row - 1 >= 0 && board[row-1][i] == 1){
        return true;
    }
}
```

**(2)** Then remove the offset from your remove and set queen methods

```
private void setQueen(int row, int column) {
    if(row < BOARD_SIZE && column < BOARD_SIZE)
        board[row][column] = QUEEN;
} // end setQueen

private void removeQueen(int row, int column) {
   if(row < BOARD_SIZE && column < BOARD_SIZE)
       board[row][column] = EMPTY;
} // end setQueen
```

**(3)** Ensure you loop from 0 to BOARD_SIZE - 1 inside placeQueens(...) method

```
while ( !queenPlaced && (row < BOARD_SIZE)  )  {
```

**(4)** Finally start at index 0

```
q.placeQueens(0);
```

Output

```
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || X || X |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
```

Comment: Also, the recursion has to start `q.placeQueens(1);` due to the way OP is accessing the array with offset -1.

Comment: yeah that offest by OP is just begging for something to go wrong, good catch @IanMc

Comment: when i start the recursion at 1 nothing still is placed in the last column @IanMc

Comment: Also at the start of the recursion, change this to: ` if (column > BOARD_SIZE)  return true`

Answer (score 1):

```
q.placeQueens(0); // here is the Error
```

Because you are going to set a Queen

```
int row = 1;
.
.
.          
setQueen(row, column);  // The program will enter with row 1 and column 0
```

And

```
private void setQueen(int row, int column) { 
    board[row-1][column-1] = QUEEN; // Here comes with row=1 and column 0
}
```

Tested with

```
q.placeQueens(1);
```

And is showing

```
| X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || X || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
| 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 || 0 |
```

I suggest you lookup some helpful java debugging tips ([Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html)).